# java-script form validation when press tab key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I faced a problem.I have total 4 text-box fields and a submit button each box are required. But i want to do, when press tab key it does not need jump to second field if those field are empty,give error with red color border otherwise jump to second text field.`[JSFidle][1]`

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in your question or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: can you make it on jsfiddle ??

Comment: I think what you are looking for is based on `tabindex`, but you'd need to specify some kind of order so that when one field is valid, then you could move on to the next. Here is the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

Comment: you can also use HTML5 validation it`s very easy and quick solution it will save your time

Comment: You can use HTML 5 validation, but that will not make it so a user cannot tab to the next field.

Comment: here is [JSFIELD](http://jsfiddle.net/r6bw14uf/)

Comment: try with thsi http://jsfiddle.net/r6bw14uf/1/

Comment: It works but here also a problem i have 12-15 different form.so if i follow this code it need every form text box id calling so it is huge code.So i need dynamic way to do this. @ashkufaraz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like  this

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6bw14uf/6/)

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    $(this).css('border','');
    if (code == '9') {        
        if($(this).val()==''){
             $(this).next().html('this field is required!');
             $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
            $( this ).focus();
            return;
        }           
    }
 });
```

Comment: It works but here also a problem i have 12-15 different form.so if i follow this code it need every form text box id calling so it is huge code.So i need dynamic way to do this. @ashkufara

Comment: thx it works but if i skip this functions only for confirm email section so what can i do this.. @ashkufara